# Download .epub or .pdf file from a URL into ios device using xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, pdf, ios6, epub

I am new here, please help me. I want to download .epub or .pdf from a given url (eg: www.example.com./file.pdf )  and store it into my iOS device with specific name (integer), if I want open that book I can be able to check whether it is the book I want or not.

Comment: i got answer for this : use below 2 codes in view didload ()

Comment: NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pewinternet.org/~/media/Files/Reports/2008/PIP_Online%20Shopping.pdf.pdf"]];
    
    //Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

Comment: NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"11011.pdf"];
    
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
    
    //Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [webview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    
    [webview setDelegate:self];
    
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: answer your own question.. Its important to mark an answer so that it'll be helpful to the user who may refer to this question

Comment: sharanya  ,i can mark it as a answer only after 8 hrs its stack overflows rule  may be becoz iam a new user here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are several solutions available to this if you google properly.

But anyways, you can use https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking or also https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request
for your purpose.

There are also some examples you can see and refer to https://github.com/PSPDFKit/PSPDFKit-Demo and https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation

For epub reader probably you can follow this link http://ideveloperworld.blogspot.in/2011/02/epub-reader.html

Comment: Sharany :thanks ! but i already got the exact answer ,you can check  the 2 comments below my question. Thank you

Comment: but i tried that one is not working sharanya...any way next time i will do that ok

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to ur view did load or any other methodes

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.feedbooks.com/book/3471.epub"]];

//Store the Data locally as epub  File if u want pdf change the file extension  

NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3471.epub"];

[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
```